# CGContextRef with UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a subclass of UIButton where it dynamically creates the highlight state background image with CGContextRef draw.  When i place the button in a UIView, the highlight shows up fine.  When i place the button inside a UITableViewCell the highlight doesn't show.  I think it has something to do with CGContextRef because when I replace the CGContextRef outputted image with an image from the main bundle it works fine.  Is there something special that needs to be done with CGContextRef when used in a UITableViewCell?

Here is my CGContextRef code inside the initWithFrame of my UIButton subclass:

```
    //HighlightImage
    //*************************
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(bRect.size.width, bRect.size.height));   

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 1.0, 0, 1.0);
    CGMutablePathRef path = AKCGRoundedRectCreate(  CGRectOffset(bRect, 0, -bRect.origin.y), kCornerRadius);
    CGContextAddPath(context,path);
    CGPathRelease(path);

    CGContextFillPath(context);

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [self setBackgroundImage: resultingImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    //[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mainBundleImage.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: what happends if you move this code to drawRect? If you want to use custom drawing on a UITableViewCell its a good idea to put that code on a UIView which you add to the Cells ContentView.